# Avoid small margins when printing borderless with Canon Selphy on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printing, electron

I would like to print [this Codesandbox-Website](https://yoko3r.csb.app/) with the default Chrome-Printing Menu.

But even when I set marginType to "none" there are tiny margins on some sides, when removing the Perforation as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S689c.jpg). Is this a Canon Selphy related issue?

(I will need this for printing with Electron, that is documented [here](https://www.electronjs.org/de/docs/latest/api/webview-tag#webviewprintoptions))

Thanks in advance for your Feedback

Comment: This doesn't seem like a soft- but hardware limitation. And frankly, a quite understandable one. The paper intake mechanisms of all printers are mechanical and thus cannot position every sheet in the very same spot. Having no margin whatsoever could result in cut-off prints, ink spilled over the printer's internals or hot toner evaporated into the air, which is obviously not what you want. All office software I have seen warns you about missing margins and all desktop printers I have seen add a margin of their own when there is none. There's nothing you could do, but I'll stand corrected.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Thanks for your response. I am also thinking, that this is related to a Hardware/Firmware issue. But it is interesting that everything is working fine (no margins), when using the System Dialog Printing Dialog with a Scale Factor. Changing the Scale Factor for the Chrome-Printer Dialog has no effect for the margins in contrast.
So there seems to be a difference between the system dialog and the Chrome-Printer Dialog. And I have to use the Chrome-Printer Dialog.